# How to programmatically add a filter that requires a relationship to a view

Tags: views

I have a view filtering out a specific node by nid, and it was working until I added a relationship. I want to filter based on the nid of the target of the relationship, not the base table nid. Here is my code, pre-relationship:

```
$options = array(
  'operator' => '!=',
  'value' => array('value' => $nid),
);
$view->add_item ($display_name, 'filter', 'node', 'nid', $options);
```

I tried replacing `nid` with the view relationship base field alias, but that didn't seem to be recognized at all. How do I indicate to Views that this filter should work via the relationship?

Answer (score 2):

I figured this out by a stroke of luck after posting this. Here is what I did:

```
// Get a list of all relationships on the view display
$relationships = $view->get_items('relationship', $display_name);
// In case there are no relationships, set this to null by default.
$last_relationship = null;
if (!empty($relationships)) {
  // @todo: is the last relationship always the one whose ID goes with the returned entities?
  $last_relationship = array_pop($relationships);
}
// Filter out the (un)desired item.
$options = array(
  'operator' => '!=',
  'value' => array('value' => $id),
);
if ($last_relationship) {
  $options['relationship'] = $last_relationship['id'];
}
$view->add_item($display_name, 'filter', $view->base_table, $view->base_field, $options);
```

Comment: Comparing this to your original code, I'd say, it can't be all luck `:p`